# How can I be certain I exist?

Tags: logic

The question is simply:

How can I be certain I exist? Or anything in this "world" for that matter?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! This question is a little broad for our format. Please have a look at the [help] and the [tour]. Questions should be answerable in a few paragraphs, and should not invite to discussion. I'm voting to close this question now because it doesn't meet those requirements, but if you [edit] it it can always be reopened.

Comment: @nir not sure where you're coming from on this. This is first and foremost a stack exchange. The topic is philosophy, but the rules comes first because they are what makes the site work. / hopefully, the people using it do love philosophy. (**please move further discussion to meta**).

Comment: @virmaior, something of that sort is probably what the people of Athens told Socrates as they sentenced him to death. this website tolerates a lot of silly questions and even sillier answers, but a simple question that Descartes could have asked or answered is put on hold - what a joke...

Comment: @nir okay, let's simplify: you're not Socrates and this isn't Athens. I'm not a politician, poet, or crafstman. I don't propose the death penalty. This is an online Q&A website with specific limitations. If you want to change the policies, **we have a *meta* where you can propose changes and raise objections -- quibbling here demonstrates rather that you misunderstand the entire forum.** You can even propose that you get treated like an Olympic winner with all you can eat food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of Descartes' *cogito ergo sum*? I think therefore I am?

In the Meditations, Descartes asks and answers your very question. The 350 years old text is very readable and exciting and you can find it here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/phi/desc/med.txt

He deals with your specific question in the second meditation; here is an excerpt:

> I suppose, then, that all the things that I see are
>   false; I persuade myself that nothing has ever existed of all
>   that my fallacious memory represents to me.  I consider that I
>   possess no senses; I imagine that body, figure, extension,
>   movement and place are but the fictions of my mind.  What,
>   then, can be esteemed as true?  Perhaps nothing at all, unless
>   that there is nothing in the world that is certain.
>
> But how can I know there is not something different from
>   those things that I have just considered, of which one cannot
>   have the slightest doubt?  Is there not some God, or some
>   other being by whatever name we call it, who puts these
>   reflections into my mind?  That is not necessary, for is it
>   not possible that I am capable of producing them myself?  I
>   myself, am I not at least something?  But I have already
>   denied that I had senses and body.  Yet I hesitate, for what
>   follows from that?  Am I so dependent on body and senses that
>   I cannot exist without these?  But I was persuaded that there
>   was nothing in all the world, that there was no heaven, no
>   earth, that there were no minds, nor any bodies:  was I not
>   then likewise persuaded that I did not exist?  Not at all; of
>   a surety I myself did exist since I persuaded myself of
>   something [or merely because I thought of something].  But
>   there is some deceiver or other, very powerful and very
>   cunning, who ever employs his ingenuity in deceiving me.  Then
>   without doubt I exist also if he deceives me, and let him
>   deceive me as much as he will, he can never cause me to be
>   nothing so long as I think that I am something.  So that after
>   having reflected well and carefully examined all things, we
>   must come to the definite conclusion that this proposition:  I
>   am, I exist, is necessarily true each time that I pronounce
>   it, or that I mentally conceive it.

What do you think of it?

Answer (score -3):

Without giving too many logical reasons, I'll just give you a comprehend-able reason.

Try hitting yourself hard,or if that doesn't make you certain then drown yourself until you are certain of your existence; if not by then, then I don't know anything else!

Comment: That answer is not at all satisfying, it's rather stupid and not a honest attempt to answering the question.

Comment: The question isn't satisfying either. And seriously, if you are not sure yourself that you exist, why would anyone else care?

Comment: I meant no disrespect, if you think you don't exist, then you won't drown! Or hitting you...won't hurt you! Can you tell me otherwise?